# converting a position list to a word list

Tags: python-3.x

i have a piece of code that has created a position list from multiple lists of words , an example of this is:
ask not what you can do for your country ask what your country can do for you

some people enjoy computing others do not enjoy computing

i will use this as my last sentence as i do not need another sentence

have the position lists of:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 8]

i now need to create a piece of code that can do the opposite:
recreate the sentences from the position list

i am stuck at how to attempt this and would appreciate any help.

if this is unclear please say so i can make any ammends to my wording

Comment: what information does the position list capture? What is the meaning of each value in a position list?

Comment: each value is the position of the first time each word first occurs if the value repeats later in the list it means that the word has been repeated

Answer (score 0):

```
In [22]: sentence = "some people enjoy computing others do not enjoy computing".split()

In [23]: poslist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 4]

In [24]: ' '.join(sentence[i-1] for i in poslist)
Out[24]: 'some people enjoy computing others do not enjoy computing some enjoy enjoy computing others do not computing'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ["ask not what you can do for your country ask what your country can do for you",
"some people enjoy computing others do not enjoy computing",
"i will use this as my last sentence as i do not need another sentence"]

pos_lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 8]]

def regenerate_text(position_list, index):
    sentence = []
    for position in position_list:
        sentence.append(index[position])
    return " ".join(sentence)

for sentence, pos_list in zip(data, pos_lists):
    sentence_tokens = sentence.split()
    index = dict()
    for pos, word in enumerate(sentence_tokens):
        if word not in index:
            index.update({pos+1: word})
    new_sentence = regenerate_text(pos_list, index)
    assert(sentence == new_sentence)
```

You can create a dictionary of the positions and corresponding tokens in the sentence and then use the dictionary to get the final list of tokens. `regenerate_text` converts the position list and a dictionary to create the sentence.